# Creating 8/12 - 4/12 grid whith different amount of columns in

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling to create a grid banner which contains 2 columns 8/12 and 4/12 where the 8/12 contain 1 div which fills everything and the 4/12 contains 2 on top of eachother. There should be 20 pix between the two columns andbetween the two divs in the 4/12. It should look something like below where the two columns height always is aligned?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var h;
  h = $('#one').height();
  alert(h);
  $('#ttcont').height(h)
});
```

```css
  #one {
    width: 66%;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  #two {
    height: 49.5%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
  }
  #three {
    height: 49.5%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
  }
  #ttcont {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
  }
  #cont {}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="cont">
  <div id="one">
    jkhdfc
    <br>jkhdfc
    <br>jkhdfc
    <br>jkhdfc
    <br>jkhdfc
    <br>jkhdfc
    <br>jkhdfc
    <br>jkhdfc
    <br>jkhdfc
    <br>jkhdfc
    <br>jkhdfc
    <br>jkhdfc
    <br>

  </div>
  <div id="ttcont">
    <div id="two">
      hjgdcf
    </div>
    <div id="three">
      hjdv
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is here that it wont adjust height when adjusting browser

Comment: Problem will be that @PeterPik wants a solution that adjusts the small boxes' height no matter what height the 8-12 has. Your example assumes the 8-12 has a fixed height of 400px. For `height: 50%;` to work for the 4-12s the parent container needs a fixed height. Just measure the 8-12s height with JS on document ready state, set it explicitly via JS and you're good to go.

Comment: @peter Pik i have edited my answer, this works as you wanted it to :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 4-12s to automatically adapt in height you need to explicitly set the surrounding container's height in css. Since I assume this depends on content, you have to use a tiny bit of Javascript to measure its rendered height and then apply that as a css style to it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var boxcontainerHeight = $('.boxcontainer').height();
  $('.boxcontainer').css('height', boxcontainerHeight + 'px');
});
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.boxcontainer {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 500px;
}
.boxcontainer:after {
  content: ".";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0px;
}
.big {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 66.6666666%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 20px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.small {
  color: #fff;
  height: 50%;
  border: 20px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.small+.small {
  border-top-width: 0;
}
.small .boxcontent {
  background-color: #a00;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Boxes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="boxcontainer">
    <div class="big">
      <div class="boxcontent">8-12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      <div class="boxcontent">4-12</div>
    </div>
    <div class="small">
      <div class="boxcontent">4-12</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#d8, #d4 div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
}
#d8, #d4 {
    height: 200px;
}
#d8 {
    width: 60%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
#d4 div {
    width: 30%;
    height: calc(50% - 11px);
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#d4 div:first-child {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="d8"></div>
<div id="d4">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

A little CSS solves it.

Comment: I see you've used percentages however when i adjust the browser it aint adjusting the width and height?

Comment: Oh, i clipped the body size for testing. Just set those to 100vh and 100vw. Updating...

Comment: now it seem to work, one last question why u applying only 60, 30% width and not 66 and 33?

Comment: i've added images in your example but it does not seem to adjust the height? when adjusting browser size